# How to apply "position: sticky" to an angular-material card in a flex-layout?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, sticky, angular-flex-layout

I'm trying to get an angular-material card to be sticky. Problem is it didn't seem to work, and I don't get why.

Is it because the parent component got a FxLayout ? I couldn't get my card to be sticky, here my code:

HTML

```html
<section fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="5%">
  <article class="progress-card" fxFlex="30">
    <mat-card fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
      <mat-card-title><h2>PROGRESSION</h2></mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>Text here</p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </article>
  <article fxFlex="70" fxLayout="column">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-title><h2>CONTENT</h2></mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>Text here</p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </article>
</section>
```

CSS

```css
.progress-card {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

I'd like to get the "progress-card" to stay sticky on the top of the screen as I scroll down to read the other card content.

Thanks for your help and your time.

Answer (score 1):

```css
section.stycky {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
body {
    height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<section fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="5%" class="stycky">
  <article class="progress-card" fxFlex="30">
    <mat-card fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
      <mat-card-title><h2>PROGRESSION</h2></mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>Text here</p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </article>
</section>

<section fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="5%">
  <article fxFlex="70" fxLayout="column">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-title><h2>CONTENT</h2></mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>Text here</p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Snippet works like a charm but it doesn't move a thing on my own code. I'm maybe missing some informations to give but this project is pretty huge... I'll come back with more infos, thx again !

Comment: @Alvard You are welcome. section - parent. You should think about the construction. In my code, the construction is different. I did two sections. Perhaps you can find a better option. But my native language is Russian. English is a second language, I know it worse, maybe I misunderstand something. But, I wanted to help you. On the Russian site I was blocked unfairly. From time to time I can help here.